# How to define a model in PyMC3 with one parameter constrained to the same value for several conditions

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I want to write a model, like the one below. The main idea is that I have several conditions (or treatments) all parameters are estimated for each condition independently, except the kappa parameter that is the same for all conditions.

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    trace_per_condition = []
    # define the kappa hyperparameter
    kappa = pm.Gamma('kappa', 1, 0.1)
    for condition in range(0, ncond):
        z_cond = z[condition]
        # define the mu hyperparameter
        mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1)
        # define the prior
        theta = pm.Beta('theta', mu * kappa, (1 - mu) * kappa, shape=len(z_cond))
        # define the likelihood
        y = pm.Binomial('y', p=theta, n=trials, observed=z_cond)
    # Generate a MCMC chain
        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step1 = pm.Metropolis([theta, mu])
        step2 = pm.NUTS([kappa])
        trace = pm.sample(1000, [step1, step2], progressbar=False)
        trace_per_condition.append(trace)
```

When I run the model I get the following message.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:513:  UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: mu handle_disconnected(elem)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:533: UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: <DisconnectedType>
  handle_disconnected(rval[i])
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:513: UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: theta
  handle_disconnected(elem)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 46, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/tuning/starting.py", line 80, in find_MAP
    start), fprime=grad_logp_o, disp=disp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 777, in fmin_bfgs
    res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 832, in _minimize_bfgs
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 281, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/tuning/starting.py", line 75, in grad_logp_o
    return nan_to_num(-dlogp(point))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/blocking.py", line 119, in __call__
    return self.fa(self.fb(x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/model.py", line 284, in __call__
    return self.f(**state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 516, in __call__
    self[k] = arg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 452, in __setitem__
    self.value[item] = value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 413, in __setitem__
    "of the inputs of your function for duplicates." % str(item)) 
TypeError: Ambiguous name: mu - please check the names of the inputs of your function for duplicates.
```

Edit
Following the answer of chris-fonnesbeck I tried the following:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    trace_per_condition = []
    # define the kappa hyperparameter
    kappa = pm.Gamma('kappa', 1, 0.1)
    for condition in range(0, ncond):
        z_cond = z[condition]
        # define the mu hyperparameter
        mu = pm.Beta('mu_%i' % condition, 1, 1)
        # define the prior
        theta = pm.Beta('theta_%i' % condition, mu * kappa, (1 - mu) * kappa, shape=len(z_cond))
        # define the likelihood
        y = pm.Binomial('y_%i' % condition, p=theta, n=trials, observed=z_cond)
    # Generate a MCMC chain
        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step1 = pm.Metropolis([theta, mu])
        step2 = pm.NUTS([kappa])
        trace = pm.sample(10000, [step1, step2], start=start, progressbar=False)
        trace_per_condition.append(trace)
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:513:
UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable  
that  is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a  
non-differentiable operator: mu_1
handle_disconnected(elem)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:533: 
UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable 
that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a 
non-differentiable operator: <DisconnectedType>
handle_disconnected(rval[i])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py:513: 
UserWarning: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable 
that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a 
non-differentiable operator: theta_1
handle_disconnected(elem)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 43, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/tuning/starting.py", line 80, in find_MAP
    start), fprime=grad_logp_o, disp=disp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 777, in fmin_bfgs
    res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 837, in _minimize_bfgs
    old_fval = f(x0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 281, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/tuning/starting.py", line 72, in logp_o
    return nan_to_high(-logp(point))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/blocking.py", line 119, in __call__
    return self.fa(self.fb(x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-3.0-py2.7.egg/pymc/model.py", line 283, in __call__
    return self.f(**state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 482, in __call__
    raise TypeError("Too many parameter passed to theano function")
TypeError: Too many parameter passed to theano function
```

The UserWarning are related to the optimization of the starting point and is removed If I do not use pm.find_MAP(). The rest of the error persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you're sampling each time you add a condition, I think you probably want to pull that out of the loop.

Also, you don't need to define a separate variables for each mu, theta, y for each condition. 
For example, if your data is in `data` in columns, yu should be able to do something like

```
with pm.Model() as model:

    kappa = pm.Gamma('kappa', 1, 0.1)

    mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1, shape=ncond)

    mu_c = mu[data.condition]
    theta = pm.Beta('theta', mu_c * kappa, (1 - mu_c) * kappa, shape=len(data))

    y = pm.Binomial('y', p=theta, n=data.trials, observed=data.z_cond)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define PyMC objects in a loop, you have to give them different names at each iteration. For example you might define:

```
mu = pm.Beta('mu_%i' % condition, 1, 1)
```

That should eliminate the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, but now I get another error. I edit the question to add the new error.